# Using car::Anova package for a doubly-multivariate MANOVA in R

Tags: r, r-car

I'm trying to run a repeated-measures MANOVA in R, which also contains a number of dependent variables (key outcome variables of behavioural tasks). The repeated-measures are due to a cross-over design, in which individuals took a drug and placebo (in randomised order).

The code I'm running looks like this:

```
imatrix <- matrix(c(
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 
  0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
  0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1,
  0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
  0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1,
  0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
  0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1
), 12, 7, byrow=TRUE)
colnames(imatrix) <- c("BCST", "CGT", "AST", "AGN", "DDT", "FERT", "NAC")
(imatrix <- list(measure=imatrix[,1:6], condition=imatrix[,7]))
contrasts(condition_factor) <- matrix(c(-1,1,1, -1), ncol=2)

doubly.mod<-lm(cbind(bcst_nac$totPersErr,bcst_placebo$totPersErr,cantab_nac$CGT.Delay.aversion,cantab_placebo$CGT.Delay.aversion,cantab_nac$AST.Switching.cost..Mean..correct.,cantab_placebo$AST.Switching.cost..Mean..correct.,cantab_nac$AGN.Affective.response.bias..Mean.,cantab_placebo$AGN.Affective.response.bias..Mean.,aucs_NAC,aucs_placebo,fert_nac$FERTACCHA,fert_placebo$FERTACCHA)~1))
Manova(doubly.mod, imatrix=imatrix, type =3)
```

The result is this error: Error in Anova.III.mlm(mod, SSPE, error.df, idata, idesign, icontrasts,  : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
However, when I change imatrix back from a list to a matrix, I get this error response:

Error in do.call(cbind, imatrix) : second argument must be a list

I've based this off the example from the car::Anova package about doubly multivariate analyses. Please let me know if you can help, or if I can add anything to make this question clearer.